# OTG Is it possible to connect two devices

Tags: usb-on-the-go

I would like to be able to copy files from SD card (through card reader) to USB flash drive. All is connected through OTG USB Hub, but all the apps I found mount only one OTG device at a time. Is there any way to connect two at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

YES - it is possible. It seems thought your phone/tablet has to be rooted. I've tried all the apps I found without root and could only connect one device at a time. Today I rooted my tablet and got Stick Mount app. Now everything works great - I can  copy files between SD Card and USB Drive, which is what I wanted.

Here is the link to the app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount

Answer (score -1):

No it's not possible ! I have tried doing that myself and a error pops up ! So, without doing any extra terrestrial tricks its not possible !

Comment: According to comments you can with that app (root): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.stickmount&hl=pl

Comment: Agreed. I've seen this noted on different apps in my list: [Mount Manager](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_storagemedia#group_533). Seems there are some extra-terrestrial developers around :)

Comment: Whoo... that sure do looks extra-terrestrial to me ! Any I would say Android had space for this nuisance too but it can be done by removing the barriers! Staying inside the boundaries isn't going to work things out ! :D

Comment: I managed to do it with root - see my answer.

Comment: @MichalDymel well, that's great! I think I need to start digging up the things a little more ! ;)